# How to send result of a function in foreachPartition to the driver node?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark program in which each executor node processes some parts of my dataset and provides a result for each part. The result is an object. I need to send results of executors to the driver node for further analysis.

```
partitions.foreachPartition(iter => { var result = doSomethingWithIter(iter);});
```

How can I send `result`s in `foreachPartition` to the driver node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition you cannot. Function you want `pass` to `foreachPartition` is:

```
Iterator[_] => Unit
```

There is no result to be send back. If you want to get results, `mapPartitions` and `collect` the output.

```
partitions.mapPartition(iter => Iterator(doSomethingWithIter(iter))).collect()
```